# MySQL best practice: matching prefixes

Tags: mysql

I have a table with codes and an other table with prefixes. I need to match the (longest) prefix for each code.

There is also a secondary scope in which I have to restrict prefixes (this involves bringing in other tables). I don't think this would matter in most cases, but here is a simplified (normalized) scheme (I have to set **item.prefix_id**):

```
group (id)
subgroup (id, group_id)
prefix (id, subgroup_id, prefix)
item (id, group_id, code, prefix_id)
```

It is allright to cache the length of the prefix in a new field and index it. It is allright to cache the group_id in prefix table (although groups are fairly small tables, in most cases I don't think any performance increase is gained). *item* table contains a few hundred thousand records, prefix contains at most 500.

**Edit:**

Sorry If the question was not defined enough. When using the word "prefix" I actually mean it, so the codes **have to start** with the actual prefix.

```
subgroup
id   group_id
-------------
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2

prefix
id   subgroup_id  prefix
------------------------
1    1            a
2    2            abc
3    2            123
4    4            abcdef

item
id   group_id     code    prefix_id
-----------------------------------
1    1            abc123  NULL
2    1            abcdef  NULL
3    1            a123    NULL
4    2            abc123  NULL
```

The expected result for the prefix column is (item.id, item.prefix_id):

(1, 2) Because: subroups 1, 2, 3 are under group 1, the code `abc123` starts with the the  prefix `a` and the prefix `abc` and `abc` is the logest of the two, so we take the id of `abc` which is 2 and put it into `item.prefix_id`.

(2, 2) Because: even though prefix {4} (which is `abcdef`) is the logest matching prefix, it's subgroup (which is 4) is under group 2 but the item is under group 1, so we can choose from subgroups 1, 2, 3 and still `abc` is the logest match out of the three possible prefixes.

(3, 1) Because: `a` is the logest match.

(4, NULL) Because: item 4 is under group 2 and the only prefix under group 2 is `abcdef` which is no match to `abc123` (because `abc123` does not start with `abcdef`).

But as I said the whole groping thing is **not essential part of the question**. My main concern is to match a table with possible prefixes to a table of strings, and how to do it the *best* way. (Best meaning an optimal tradeoff between readability, maintainability and performance - hence the 'best prectice' in the title).

Currently I'm doing something like:

```
UPDATE item USE INDEX (code3)
    LEFT JOIN prefix ON prefix.length=3 AND LEFT(item.code,3)=prefix.prefix
    LEFT JOIN subgroup ON subgroup.id=prefix.subgroup_id
WHERE subgroup.group_id == item.group_id AND
    item.segment_id IS NULL
```

Where `code3` is a `KEY code3 (segment_id, group_id, code(3))`. - And the same logic is repeate with 1, 2, 3 and 4 as length. It seems pretty efficient, but I don't like the presence of duplication in it (4 queries for a single operation). - of course this is in the case when the maximum legth of prefixes is 4.

*Thanks for everyone for sharing your ideas this far.*

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you do with two prefixes of the same length?

Comment: @vbence What is the type of column `code`? if varchar, then what length of varchar? And the same question about prefix.

Comment: There are two places in the system where this logic is used. In one case it is up to 8 characters in the other it is a fixed length of 4. They are alphanumeric stored on VARCHAR fields. There are no identical prefixes, so there is maximum one match for each length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is allright to cache the group_id in prefix table.

So let's create column `group_id` in table **prefix** and fill the column with the appropriate values. I assume that you know how to do this, so let's go to the next step.

The biggest performance benefit we will get from this **composite** index:

```
ALTER TABLE `prefix` ADD INDEX `c_index` (
    `group_id` ASC, 
    `prefix` ASC
);
```

And the **UPDATE** statement:

```
UPDATE item i
SET 
    prefix_id = (
        SELECT p.id
        FROM prefix p USE INDEX (`c_index`)
        WHERE 
            p.group_id = i.group_id AND 
            p.prefix IN (
                LEFT(i.code, 4), 
                LEFT(i.code, 3), 
                LEFT(i.code, 2), 
                LEFT(i.code, 1)
            )                
        ORDER BY LENGTH(p.prefix) DESC
        LIMIT 1        
    )
```

In this example I assume that prefix is variable length {1,4}. Together I decided to use **IN** clause instead of **LIKE** for to get the full benefit of **c_index**.

Comment: I added some sample data for clarification of the problem.

Comment: I think you are VERY close to what vbence needs for his update query.  One problem though.  Your query just grabs by the group ID without respect to a matching text from the "Prefix.Prefix = Item.Code" (ie: the Item code must start with the same value as Prefix.prefix it is joined against...)  Fix that, and I think you have what is needed.

Comment: @DRapp Yeah, but it's not so simple because the modification will not let us use the index for **ORDER BY**.

Comment: +1 It seems like it gets the job done. As long as the "best practice" part of the question goes: is there a way to still use indexes without hardcoding 1, 2, 3, 4? - It seems to me that MySQL is in desperate need of a STARTSWITH function as this kind of problem can be best solved on the lower level (with reading the existing indexes a bit differently).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm overly simplifying, should be as simple as...  Start an inner pre-query to get the longest prefix (regardless of if multiple have the same length per code)

```
select
      PreQuery.Code,
      P2.ID,
      P2.SubGroup_ID,
      P2.Prefix 
   From
      ( select
              i.code,
              max( length( trim( p.Prefix ))) as LongestPrefix
           from
              item i
                 join prefix p
                    on i.prefix_id = p.id
           group by
              i.code ) PreQuery
      Join item i2
         on PreQuery.Code = i2.Code
         Join Prefix P2
            on i2.Prefix_ID = P2.ID
            AND PreQuery.LongestPrefix = length( trim( P2.Prefix )))
```

Now, if you want to do something special about those where there are multiple with the same prefix length, it will need some adjusting, but this should get it for you.

Comment: `item.prefix_id` has NULL values, the task is to set its value.

Comment: @vbence, then can you provide a handful of rows of each respective table to show what you DO have???

Comment: Every field has the correct values except item.prefix_id - As I wote in the original post: "I have to set item.prefix_id". I will provide some more information in the morning.

Comment: I added some sample data for clarification of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To re-answer since you are trying to UPDATE elements, try the following update query.  Now here's the catch around this... The "PreQuery" will actually return ALL matching prefixes for a given item... However, since the order is based on the Prefix Length, for those entries that have more than one matching "prefix", it will first be updated with the shortest prefix, then hit the record with the next longer prefix, and finally end with whichever has the longest for the match.  So at the end, it SHOULD get you what you need.

That being said (and I can't specifically test now), if it is only updating based on the FIRST entry found for a given ID, then just make the order in DESCENDING order of the prefix length.

```
    update Item,
           ( SELECT 
                   I.ID, 
                   P.ID Prefix_ID, 
                   P.Prefix, 
                   I.Code, 
                   LENGTH( TRIM( P.Prefix )) as PrefixLen 
                FROM 
                   Item I 
                      JOIN SubGroup SG 
                         ON I.Group_ID = SG.Group_ID 
                            JOIN Prefix P 
                               ON SG.ID = P.SubGroup_ID 
                              AND LEFT( P.Prefix, LENGTH( TRIM( P.Prefix ))) 
                                = LEFT( I.Code, LENGTH( TRIM( P.Prefix ))) 
                ORDER BY 
                   I.ID,
                   LENGTH( TRIM( P.Prefix ))  ) PreQuery
      set 
         Prefix_ID = PreQuery.Prefix_ID
      where 
         ID = PreQuery.ID
```